# Prevent shapes from clipping into each other

Tags: collision, slick2d

I just started to port my game to slick2d and I want mine entities to collide with each other.
I know that `shapeA.intersects(shapeB)` checks if two shapes intersect but I want them to collide so that they aren't able to overlap each other.
I would be easy if the shapes were only rectangles but that's not the case.
So is there any way to perform this in an efficent way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully i got your question right.

To do this you need to implement collision to your game. An approach to accomplish this would be to assume your shape is for instance *x* coordinates a head of its current position.

This would mean you always have to check whether two shapes are intersecting with each other when they are moving, if they would intersect on the next movement they are not allowed to move a head, otherwise they would obviously intersect or collide. You can adapt this approach completly to your needs, for example you could let them collide and then set them back so that they are not getting stuck into each other.

There are a lot of tutorials regarding this topic and different approaches, you should check them out.

Comment: I found a solution. I wrote a velocity handler that calculates the relation between the x any y velocity and creates a step size in which the shapes moves. The handler checks after every step if it intersects with another shape. If it's the case, the position gets resetted to the last step.

Comment: Great that you found a solution :)